# How to stub a method decorator using mock?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, stub

How can I use python [mock](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock/) to stub out the behavior of the method decorators so that I don't depend on them to test the current method?

```
import utils
class Router(object):
    @utils.with_user
    @utils.formatted_response('resources', with_pagination=True)
    def get_resources(self, user_id=None, offset=None, limit=None):
        # do stuff
        pass
```

I have already tried:

```
# @patch('utils.with_tenant')
# @patch.object(utils, 'with_tenant')
def test_stub_decorator(self):
    # patch('utils.with_tenant')
    # patch.object(utils, 'with_tenant')
```

And none of these seem to work! Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

For mocking decorator, you need to mock them earlier (before load that module):

```
from mock import patch
# mock the retry decorator before any module loads it
patch('utils.with_user', lambda x: x).start()
import utils  # or any module which imports utils
```